# Show an Array of JButtons one after another with a timer [JAVA SWING]

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe, jbutton

I am making a Color game in which when I click on start a chain of colors will be shown. Now I have to click on my 4 color buttons and match the shown chain.
If I win, the chain adds a color (Level up) if I lose the chain loses a color (Level down).

My problems right now :

1. If I overlap the shown colors to match, I will only see the first index of the Array. I need to make it to show all Indexes of the JButton [] like every 2 seconds. I tried it with timer but it still show only the first one.
2. If I level up, I can add a color to the need to match array, but If I level down, I cant delete the last added color. I know there is no way to remove something from an Array, but is there a workaround. Right now I am making the player lose completely if he doesnt match the scheme.

````
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Random;
  import javax.swing.*;

public class Farbgedaechtnisspiel {
  private static int startLevel = 1;
  private static int gameLevel = 3;
  private static List<Integer> gameArray = new ArrayList<>();
  private static List<Integer> userArray = new ArrayList<>();
  private static int save = 0;
  private static int count = 0;
  private static JButton [] b;
  private static final Color red = new Color(255, 0, 0);
  private static final Color green = new Color(0, 255, 0);
  private static final Color blue = new Color(0, 0, 255);
  private static final Color yellow = new Color(255, 255, 0);
  private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Farbgedächtnisspiel");
  private static JLabel levelTxt;




  public static void main(String[] args) {
      // create mainframe
      new Farbgedaechtnisspiel();
  }


  public Farbgedaechtnisspiel () {
      createFrame(frame);
      levelTxt = new JLabel("Level: " + startLevel);
      frame.add(levelTxt);
      levelTxt.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 40));
      // create 4 color buttons + start/exit
      b = new JButton[7];
      for(int i = 0;i<b.length;i++){
          b[i] = new JButton();
          frame.add(b[i]);
      }


      // create button layout
      createButtons();



      // button listeners
      b[4].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              // start Game -> show taskArray

              levelTxt.setBounds(550, 200, 200, 200);

              startGame(gameLevel);
              }});



      b[5].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              System.exit(0);
          }
      });


      b[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              userArray.add(1);
              save++;
          }
      }
      );

      b[1].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              userArray.add(2);
              save++;
          }
      });

      b[2].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              userArray.add(3);
              save++;
          }
      });
      b[3].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              userArray.add(4);
              save++;
          }
      });

      b[6].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              boolean result = compareArrays(userArray, gameArray);
              if (result){
                  gameLevel++;
                  save = 0;
                  startLevel++;
                  levelTxt.setText("Level: " + startLevel);
              } else {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Sie haben verloren");
                  new Farbgedaechtnisspiel();
                  System.exit(1);
              }
              startGame(gameLevel);
          }
      });

      // make frame visible

      frame.setVisible(true);
  }




  public static void startGame(int gameLevel){
      int x = 100;
      JButton [] tmp = new JButton[gameLevel];
      for(int i = 0;i<tmp.length;i++) {
          tmp[i] = new JButton();
          tmp[i].setBackground(randomColor());
          tmp[i].setOpaque(true);
          tmp[i].setBorderPainted(false);
          frame.add(tmp[i]);
          if (tmp[i].getBackground() == red) {
              gameArray.add(1);
          } else if (tmp[i].getBackground() == blue) {
              gameArray.add(2);
          } else if (tmp[i].getBackground() == green) {
              gameArray.add(3);
          } else if (tmp[i].getBackground() == yellow) {
              gameArray.add(4);
          }


      }

      for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
          tmp[i].setBounds(x, 50, 100, 100);
          x+=100;
      }

      // for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
      //    tmp[i].setBounds(450, 50, 300, 299);
      //    x += 100;
      // }
  }

  public static void createButtons() {
      int x = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
          b[i].setBounds(x, 0, 200, 200);
          x += 200;
      }
      b[0].setBackground(red);
      b[0].setOpaque(true);
      b[0].setBorderPainted(false);
      b[1].setBackground(blue);
      b[1].setOpaque(true);
      b[1].setBorderPainted(false);
      b[2].setBackground(green);
      b[2].setOpaque(true);
      b[2].setBorderPainted(false);
      b[3].setBackground(yellow);
      b[3].setOpaque(true);
      b[3].setBorderPainted(false);
      b[4].setBounds(150,600,300,200);
      b[4].setText("Start");
      b[5].setBounds(450, 600, 300, 200);
      b[5].setText("Beenden");
      b[6].setBounds(750, 600, 300, 200);
      b[6].setText("Continue");
      b[0].setBounds(200, 400, 200, 200);
      b[1].setBounds(400, 400, 200, 200);
      b[2].setBounds(600, 400, 200, 200);
      b[3].setBounds(800, 400, 200, 200);
  }


  public static boolean compareArrays(List<Integer> userArray, List<Integer> gameArray){
      return userArray.equals(gameArray);
  }


  public static void createFrame(JFrame frame){
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(1200,800);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setLayout(null);
      frame.setResizable(false);
  }


  public static Color randomColor () {
      Random rand = new Random();
      int randomNum = rand.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;
      return switch (randomNum) {
          case 1 -> red;
          case 2 -> green;
          case 3 -> blue;
          case 4 -> yellow;
          default -> null;
      };
  }


}```
````

Comment: *"My problems right now"* ..are that you forgot to ask ***one*** question on this Q&A site. Of course, if you have more than one question, you are free to ask each on a separate question thread. Make sure each thread has code *specific* to that question, in the form of a [mre].

Comment: It appears that you're making a Simon game.  You should keep the colors in a java.util.List.  That way you can add a Color to the end of the List, and remove a Color from the beginning or the end of the List.  You will need a javax.swing.Timer to show each of the Colors in your list for two seconds.